# Batch copy or move folders in AppData

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to move folders that are stored in AppData for one of my programs. I'm using the following in a batch file:

```
xcopy C:\Users\htpcn\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\userdata\addon_data\plugin.audio.pandoki\Pandoki\* E:\Music\Pandoki Tracks
```

I've also tried the move command but no luck. My guess is you can't move or copy files from this directory but I haven't had any success finding any documented limitation

Comment: Are you running as user `htpcn`?  Also, is the destination folder `E:\Music\Pandoki` or `E:\Music\Pandoki Tracks`?  If the latter, you will need to put it in quotes.

Comment: yes, admin user is `htpcn` and destination folder does have a space in the title `Pandoki Tracks`. Does it need to look like this: `"E:\Music\Pandoki Tracks"`

Comment: Got it working by adding the quotes. Thanks!

Comment: I had success with files but I'm not able to move folders. Do I need a different command for that?

Comment: Try putting `/E` at the end of the command, which makes xcopy recursive.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again. I was able to find an explanation of the switches finally

Comment: Instead of C:\Users\htpcn\AppData\Roaming, put "%AppData%". Then it won't matter what your username, and it would still work even if you change the location of your appdata folder by modifying the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a folder has a space in it, then you need to make sure to put it in quotes in your command, so that `xcopy` doesn't treat it like a different parameter.  In this case, the folder `E:\Music\Pandoki Tracks` has a space, so it must be in quotes.

To move folders, also use the `/S` or `/E` parameter to make `xcopy` act recursively on subdirectories.  To see the full list of parameters, use `xcopy /?`

```
xcopy "C:\Users\htpcn\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\userdata\addon_data\plugin.audio.pandoki\Pandoki\*" "E:\Music\Pandoki Tracks" /E
```

It is a good practice to put all paths in quotes when passing to commands like `xcopy`.  It does no harm for paths without special characters like spaces, and it saves on debugging confusion when the path does have special characters and you don't notice.

Comment: The `/I` switch might also be helpful to avoid prompting whether `E:\Music\Pandoki Tracks` is a file or dir. in case it does not yet exist...